# Do you know of any good TFS administrator training programs?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am working on bringing TFS (Microsoft Team Foundation Server) into our organization and I was wondering if anyone had been through administrator level training on TFS that they felt was particularly valuable, or whether people just are learning these things "in the trenches" so to speak. Ideally looking for something in California but not completely opposed to travel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pluralsight's offerings are ones that I would look into. Haven't been through this training myself, but I've always heard good things about Pluralsight.

http://www.pluralsight.com/main/ilt/Course.aspx?id=AP12

Answer (score 0):

Contact Business-IQ (http://www.business-iq.com/). Their training is excellent. They just trained 12 of our developers and we are already up and running with the system three days later.

Answer (score 0):

I am signed up for a training from [New Horizons](http://www.newhorizons.com), it is course number 6215, search for that and it will come up. Will update everybody on how it went.

**Update:** Training wasn't very good, instructor didn't have much (any?) real world experience with TFS to draw upon. Got much more out of just setting it up myself and exploring the capabilities of the system. Microsoft's documentation is pretty good, especially the TFS guide on codeplex that is free (essentially a 400-500 page book on TFS real world usage).